# Adding User/Password to SOAPHeader for WebService client call with AXIS2

Tags: java, web-services, soap, apache-axis, soapheader

Please help: I am trying to call a WebService from SOAPUI and I notice that the service requires username and password which I am providing through the request parameters. I notice that raw XML contains user/password snippet added to SOAPHeader. The snippet is as below:

```
<wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"><wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-3" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"><wsse:Username>testuser</wsse:Username><wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">testpassword&amp;</wsse:Password><wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">RYadQak91mr7dB+5hyt8yw==</wsse:Nonce><wsu:Created>2011-10-24T20:13:43.039Z</wsu:Created></wsse:UsernameToken>
</wsse:Security>
```

Now the same thing I want to achieve by adding user/password details as in the below code: code snippet is:

```
org.tempuri.myService.MyServiceStub stub = new  org.tempuri.myService.MyServiceStub();

ServiceClient sc = stub._getServiceClient();
HttpTransportProperties.Authenticator auth = new HttpTransportProperties.Authenticator();
auth.setUsername("testuser");
auth.setPassword("password$");

sc.getOptions().setProperty(org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPConstants.AUTHENTICATE,auth);

org.tempuri.myService.MyServiceDocument myService4 = (org.tempuri.myService.MyServiceDocument)getTestObject(org.tempuri.myService.MyServiceDocument.class);

MyService lval = MyService4.addNewMyService();

MyServiceParameters lvParams = lval.addNewParameters();
lvParams.setA("24");
lvParams.setB("10");

lval.setParameters(lvParams);
myService4.setMyService(lval);
```

But I get following Axis fault exception, Need help in the mistake I am doing with the above code. Axis Fault Exception details:

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Exception occurred while executing service 'MyService'.
    at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.java:531)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:375)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:421)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
    at org.tempuri.myService.MyServiceStub.myService(MyServiceStub.java:182)
    at org.tempuri.myService.MyServiceTest.main(MyServiceTest.java:55)

MyServiceResponseDocument lvdoc = stub.myService(myService4);
```

Comment: I removed the earlier post, Yes I should have edited the earlier one itself. But due to pressing urgency I ended-up posting a new one.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I resolved  the issue myself, this snippet might help some one who want to add additional parameters (atleast this works for me):

The code snippet is as below:

```
OMFactory omFactory = OMAbstractFactory.getOMFactory();
OMElement omSecurityElement = omFactory.createOMElement(new QName( "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd", "Security", "wsse"), null);


OMElement omusertoken = omFactory.createOMElement(new QName("http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd", "UsernameToken", "wsu"), null);

OMElement omuserName = omFactory.createOMElement(new QName("", "Username", "wsse"), null);
omuserName.setText("myusername");

OMElement omPassword = omFactory.createOMElement(new QName("", "Password", "wsse"), null);
omPassword.addAttribute("Type","http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText",null );
omPassword.setText("mypassword");

omusertoken.addChild(omuserName);
omusertoken.addChild(omPassword);
omSecurityElement.addChild(omusertoken);
stub._getServiceClient().addHeader(omSecurityElement);
```

Comment: UsernameToken should also be in the NS wsse and not in wsu. wsu should be referred for the attribute Id in UserNameToken

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else struggling with Invalid Security Header - the answer from Shiv Gopal did not work for me - i received WSS1613: The element UsernameToken inside security header is not supported.

After basically comparing my metro client to my axis2 client and tinkering with every fragment to be 1:1 it boiled down to this:

change

```
OMElement omusertoken = omFactory.createOMElement(new QName("http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd", "UsernameToken", "wsu"), null);
```

to

```
OMElement omusertoken = omFactory.createOMElement(new QName(null, "wsse:UsernameToken", "wsse"), null);
```

And now authentication works

Answer (score 0):

This dirty code within the Stub class, generated by the axis2:wsdl2code, helped me:

```
    public void addWsSecurityHeader(String wsUser, String wsPass)
        {

    OMFactory omFactory = OMAbstractFactory.getOMFactory();
    OMElement omSecurityElement = omFactory.createOMElement(new QName( "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd", "Security", "wsse"), null);
            omSecurityElement.addAttribute("xmlns:wsu", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-%20wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd",  null);


    OMElement omusertoken = omFactory.createOMElement(new QName("http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd", "UsernameToken", "wsse"), null);
    omusertoken.addAttribute("wsu:Id","UsernameToken-87",null );

    OMElement omuserName = omFactory.createOMElement(new QName("http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd","Username", "wsse"), null);
    omuserName.setText(wsUser);

    OMElement omPassword = omFactory.createOMElement(new QName("http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd","Password", "wsse"), null);
    omPassword.addAttribute("Type","http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText",null );
    omPassword.setText(wsPass);

    omusertoken.addChild(omuserName);
    omusertoken.addChild(omPassword);
    omSecurityElement.addChild(omusertoken);
    this._getServiceClient().addHeader(omSecurityElement);
}
```

it produced the correct values for the

```
 ...<wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-87">
```

aa...

because when the namespaces of the child element coincide with parents' ones, the out put child elements are without it. So you shouldn't use empty namespace for producing tags without it. But i haven't fount how to set several xmlns for the same tag, so I made a dirty hack to create the second xmlns as a tag attribute. May be I was wrong, but it worked.